# Creating multiple Anova and Making the Result to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, anova

I have two factor data below and two numeric data and I want to make an anova test for each combination of them. Also I need them all to be in data frame so I can input them into excel. I have trouble looping them. Thank you.

```
    df <- data.frame(age_group=rep(c("1","2","3"),10),civil_status=rep(c("1","2"),15),Happy=sample(30, replace = F),GoodWork=sample(30, replace = F) )


age_happy <- aov(Happy~age_group,data=df)
summary(age_happy)
TukeyHSD(age_happy)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this code to help me shorthen things. I view the codes then copy and paste in excel but it seems that summary won't show

```
    anova_loop <- function(numeric_group,factor_group,data_group){
  group_anova <- aov(numeric_group~factor_group,data=theData2)
  print(summary(group_anova))

 group_Tukey<- TukeyHSD(group_anova, "factor_group", ordered = TRUE) 
  df_Tukey <- data.frame(group_Tukey$factor_group)


}
```